# How to convert json file to json array object for Deserializing into C# MVC model

Tags: javascript, c#, json, asp.net-web-api2, deserialization

I need to convert a json file to match a viewmodel parameter for a WebAPI 2 post (language C#).
But when it hits the API controller, the param  (data from body) is null.

My .json file to set up to match my model

```
{
  "Data": {
     "DataHeader": {
         "MessageTrackingIdentifier": "18c64415-05cc-415e-9cf1-034bdc4dbdac",
         "MessageName": "USERS"
      },
     "DataDetail": [
         {
             "CustomerCode": "0002888802",
             "CustomerName": "SGG (Pty) Limited        "
         },
         {
             "CustomerCode": "0002034092",
             "CustomerName": "AAG  (Pty) Limited        "
         }
     ]
  }
}
```

My model:

```
public class TUserModel
{
    public TUserDataModel Data { get; set; }
}

public class TUserDataModel
{
    public TDataHeader DataHeader { get; set; }
    public List<TUserModelDataDetail> DataDetail { get; set; }
}

public class TUserModelDataDetail
{
    public string CustomerCode { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
}


public class TDataHeader
{
    public string MessageTrackingIdentifier { get; set; }
    public string MessageName { get; set; }
}
```

My WebAPI 2 action

```
public IHttpActionResult PostUser([FromBody] TUserModel model)
```

Ajax postfunction:

```
   function PostUserData(viewModel)
    {
        var model = JSON.stringify(viewModel);

        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:60667/api/User",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            crossDomain: true,
            data: model,            
            success: function (reply)
            {
                $('.js-call-UserApi').css("background", "green");   
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, errorData)
            {
                alert('error: ' + JSON.stringify(jqXHR.responseText, errorData));
            }
        });
    }
```

The js call of the file to the Ajax Post function: (filename it reads is 'UserFA.json')

```
    var oXHR = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');

    function reportStatus()
    {
        if (oXHR.readyState == 4)                    // Request completed.
            PostUserData(this.responseText);         // All set. Now show the data.
    }

    oXHR.onreadystatechange = reportStatus;
    oXHR.open("GET", "UserFA.json", true);          // true = ASYNCHRONOUS REQUEST (DESIRABLE), false = SYNCHRONOUS REQUEST.
    oXHR.send();
```

Edit: The file once read in and stringified and cleaned of formatting characters

```
"{"Data": 
     {"DataHeader": {"MessageTrackingIdentifier": "18c64415-05cc-415e-9cf1-034bdc4dbdac", "MessageName": "USERS"},
      "DataDetail": 
   [      
        { "CustomerCode": "0002888802    ", "CustomerName": "SGG (Pty) Limited      "},
        { "CustomerCode": "0002034092    ", "CustomerName": "AAG  (Pty) Limited      "}
       ]  
     }
 }"
```

Thanks

Comment: `public string Data { get; set; }` // This string is not in your json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your json and model don't quite match.  The json has an object named "Data" which then contains "DataHeader" and "DataDetail" -- but in your model, these properties are all at the same level in your TUserModel object and Data is a string not an object.  If you want to change the model to match the json, then you will need to change TUserModel to:

```
public class TUserModel
{
    public TUserDataModel Data { get; set; }
}
```

And add an intermediate object, which I'm calling TUserDataModel:

```
public class TUserDataModel
{
    public TDataHeader DataHeader { get; set; }
    public List<TUserModelDataDetail> DataDetail { get; set; }
}
```

If you want to change the json and leave the model mostly the same, then remove the "Data" level, thus moving DataHeader  and DataDetail up.  You could then also remove the string "Data" property from your TUserModel class.

```
{
   "DataHeader": {
       ...
   },
   "DataDetail": [
      ...
   ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the structure is now as per yours,..but I'm  still getting null in the API method.

Comment: I added the code which calls the ajax post at the end of the question (just in case).

Comment: @NealRogers, i just created an empty WebApi project (.Net Core) in VS 2019 and added the revised model (based on my change) and a simple controller method using "[FromBody] TUserModel model" and it worked perfectly.  The model is fully populated using the exact json from your question above.  So something else is wrong.  I did the post using Postman.  Can you try POSTing the data using Postman or something similar to help isolate the issue?  If Postman works, then it's your JS.

Comment: I'll try the Postman route (not familiar with it)..but getting very late in the evening here is South africa. so,..will continue in the a.m.  But thanks so far, .. no doubt I did something dumb.
I have edited the question to reflect the model as per yours correctly now.

Comment: i used the same ajax post method, with a simpler model, which I built in js, and a simpler model to receive it on the API method, which worked, so ..I doubt it's the ajax function itself. The .json file has a lot of empty spaces in the fields it provides, but that can't affect the string datatypes in the model.

Comment: i used the same ajax post method, with a simpler model, which I built in js, and a simpler model to receive it on the API method, which worked, so ..I doubt it's the ajax function itself. The .json file has a lot of empty spaces in the fields it provides, but that can't affect the string datatypes in the model.

Comment: The extra spaces in the the string data won't matter.  When I used your json, the data came through fine, with the extra spaces.

Comment: Now that I look at your edits/updates, are the spaces after the "MessageTrackingIdentifier" field name intentional?  Are those spaces actually in your JSON?  Spaces in the string data will not matter, spaces in the field name may prevent the model-binding.  Your original json at the top doesn't show these spaces.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, there are no spaces in the field/key names,..just the data.

Comment: Thanks, just using the json string works. when reading from the file, there are formatting characters, backslashes etc which caused the problem.